# Dummy Encoding Using ColumTransformer

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have just started learning machine learning and I was watching a tutorial in which the tutor used OneHotEncoder for dummy encoding (the reason given by him was so that the categorical features don't end up having a relation between them, e.g. Spain(value 2) greater than France(value 1). Here's the code:

```
Dataset = pandas.read_csv('Data.csv')
X = Dataset.iloc[:,:3].values
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder( categorical_features=[0])
onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

While trying this on PyCharm I got the following warning :

> DeprecationWarning: The 'categorical_features' keyword is deprecated
>   in version 0.20 and will be removed in 0.22. You can use the
>   ColumnTransformer instead.   "use the ColumnTransformer instead.",
>   DeprecationWarning)

So I went and looked up the documentation of ColumnTransformer but I can't understand how to go about this.

Comment: Please see [ask], it is impossible to debug code that hasn't been given.

Comment: Plus this is a *warning*, not an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for the `ColumnTransformer` can be [found here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html#sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer).
You pass the `OneHotEncoder` to the `transformer` argument as if you were creating a `Pipeline`.

Below is an example of how to use it.

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

transformer = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ("OneHot",        # Just a name
         OneHotEncoder(), # The transformer class
         [0]              # The column(s) to be applied on.
         )
    ]
)

X = [
    ['a', 0],
    ['b', 1],
    ['a', 2]
]

print(transformer.fit_transform(X))

> [[1. 0.]
>  [0. 1.]
>  [1. 0.]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Document for [ColumnTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html#sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer)
Example to check it.
    # TODO: create a LabelEncoder object and fit it to each feature in X

```
# import preprocessing from sklearn
from sklearn import preprocessing
# 1. INSTANTIATE
# encode labels with value between 0 and n_classes-1.
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
# 2/3. FIT AND TRANSFORM
# use df.apply() to apply le.fit_transform to all columns
X_2 = X.apply(le.fit_transform)
X_2.head()
```

If you wish to see an end to end example please [check](https://www.ritchieng.com/machinelearning-one-hot-encoding/).